# Some problems with main menu and submenu when i hover

Tags: css, menu, hover

i have some trouble with my menu.

See:

[http://marketing-für-immobilien.de/](http://marketing-f%C3%BCr-immobilien.de/)

when i hover over the menu the background color change to blue and the font color turns to white. when i hover to the submenu same procedure but the main menu font color turns into blue. I cound´t find the right css to keep the white color for the main menu when i hover to the submenu.

Would be very fine, if someone can help me

Cheers
Sven

Comment: Please provide your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 different `:hover` definitions.
The first on the `li` tag of your main menu. This set the `li` background to blue.
The second is on the `a` tag of your main menu. This set the font color of the main menu to white.

And here is your mistake. If you move your cursor to the submenu, the cursor is still on the `li` tag of main menu, BUT not on the `a` tag anymore. So the second hover get off.

ADD to your CSS:

```
header.navbar nav > div > ul > li:hover {
    background-color: #004b96;
}
```

this one:

```
header.navbar nav > div > ul > li:hover a {
    color: #fff;
}
```

And remove:

```
header.navbar a:hover {
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: You are welcome. Please mark the answer as one solving your question.